# Use emacs shell (eshell) in multi-term

Tags: emacs

I just set up [Multi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm) in emacs24, i'm trying to configure it to be able to open multi-term running eshell.

**How can I do it, specify eshell as the shell program ??**

I'm trying for instance to create the equivalent with eshell:

```
(defun multi-term-bash ()
                    "Make a multi-term buffer running bash."
                    (interactive)
                    (let ((multi-term-program "/bin/bash"))
                      (multi-term)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer here is: you can't. =/
multi-term needs a native shell to run. Meanwhile eshell isn't really a shell, it's an interactive emacs mode (written entirely in elisp) which acts like a shell.

There are other ways to achieve your overall objective, shell-switcher and multi-eshell are the first that come up.
Checkout this page on emacswiki.
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellMultipleEshellBuffers